# Curl. 302 error. Followlocation does not work

Tags: php, curl

At first, sorry on my english. 
When I try to get the page from "http://www.baiterek.gov.kz/ru" by curl it show 302 error - "The document has moved here".
I set followlocation true, but it didn't help.
My curl function is:

```
function get_web_page($url) {
    $uagent = "Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) Presto/2.12.388 Version/12.14";    
    $ch = curl_init( $url );     
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);   
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $uagent);  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 120); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);      
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);   
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,"d://coo.txt");  
    $content = curl_exec( $ch );
    $err     = curl_errno( $ch );
    $errmsg  = curl_error( $ch );
    $header  = curl_getinfo( $ch );
    curl_close( $ch );   
    $header['errno']   = $err;
    $header['errmsg']  = $errmsg;
    $header['content'] = $content;
    return $header;
}
```

full situation is:
I try to parse this site from my server but the admin of this site blocked my IP. Then I saved my parser on other server. There all good. And now I try to get content from my other server, that parse this site. 
I do it like this. My server: X, other server: Y.
on Y I receive the url and echo the content and then on X `$site = get_we_page(Y?url=http://www.baiterek.gov.kz/ru);`
So on X I get 302

Comment: Hi! I check your function, and it's work good. Maybe you have something to confuse?

Comment: @maximkou, did you echo $header['content']? you got some content on russian? maybe the result depends on server?

Comment: Yes. I'm get russian content. And curl open page http://185.129.49.13/ru/ after redirects.

Comment: Maybe you have cookies, which initiate inifinite redirects?

Comment: when debugging curl, use CURLOPT_VERBOSE. add that, what output you do get?

Comment: also, $header is a misleading name, it doesn't contain the headers. maybe call it $responseInfo or something

Comment: it works here.. the 302 is followed, as proven by CURLOPT_VERBOSE and that code: http://paste.debian.net/913322/